# link PHP with Octave or Matlab

Tags: php, matlab, octave

Suppose I have a lot of math calculations which are quite tedious to implement in php. Is it possible to somehow link PHP and Octave on the server in such a way, that php sends parameters to Octave and receives answers back.

Has anyone tried anything similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution is to use [octave-daemon](http://projects.moongate.ro/octave-daemon/), which was written specifically for this purpose. Works on Linux, don't know about Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matlab compiler to make an executable matlab application, that you can call from php.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Octave can be called from PHP using the Linux command line, using commands like `exec()` or `passthru()`. Anyway, their appropriate use depends on what you are trying to do (there are no details of your problem).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, in Windows, is to compile Matlab as a DLL and include it ona web app (a WFC service, for example). At that point you have a functional "matlab service" and then you can access that service from PHP or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create a .NET component using Matlab Builder NE, and deploy it using SilverLight on the web.